# How to change value in JavaScript without saving into another variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Following is my code, in which I am uppercase some strings of an object, now when I console in the lower side its look like the scope of the method(toUpperCase in this case) only applied in the for loop. I know I can achieve the result by storing/pushing the result into another array/object, but I want to know if their is any method available/technique in JS through which the method directly applies on original variable and changes its value directly ?

**Code-**

```
var odr = {
    testkey1: "a test",
    testkey2: {
        "name": "harris",
        "city": "New York",
        "addr": "107 Suite"
    },
    testkey3: "b test",
};

if(odr.testkey2 !== undefined) {
    for(var key in odr.testkey2) {
        if(odr.testkey2.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if(typeof odr.testkey2[key] == 'string') {
                console.log(odr.testkey2[key].toUpperCase());
            }    
        }
    }
}

console.log(odr.testkey2);
```

Result -

```
Object {name: "harris", city: "New York", addr: "107 Suite"}
```

Working Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/o6d45en6/

Comment: No, I think all methods that modify a string do so, and then return a new string; why are you opposed to creating a new variable? You could (inside the `for` loop: `odr.testkey2[key] = odr.testkey2[key].toUpperCase()` if you just don't want to create a new/temporary variable to throw away.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes very true I checked and its working as per the comment, BTW I checked JS is pass by value so its not directly affecting the values..thx new to JS :) Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might misunderstand what you are asking.But String.toUpperCase() is NOT bang method which is updating its value by just calling the method.So If you want to update the value,You need to substitute.

```
if(odr.testkey2 !== undefined) {
    for(var key in odr.testkey2) {
        if(odr.testkey2.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if(typeof odr.testkey2[key] == 'string') {
                odr.testkey2[key] = odr.testkey2[key].toUpperCase();
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

FYI, in javascript,Object is always passing its reference when you substitute it.which means you cannot do this

```
var copiedObject = odr;
if(copiedObject.testkey2 !== undefined) {
    for(var key in copiedObject.testkey2) {
        if(copiedObject.testkey2.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if(typeof copiedObject.testkey2[key] == 'string') {
                copiedObject.testkey2[key] = copiedObject.testkey2[key].toUpperCase();
            }    
        }
    }
}
console.log(odr); // -> odr object has also changed. because copiedObject is just a reference of odr.
```

to avoid this, you need to `deep copy` the object.

```
var copiedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(odr));
```

or

```
var copiedObject = jQuery.extend({}, odr);
```

Comment: "*`String.toUpperCase()` is NOT bang method*" - what does that mean? What's a "bang method"?

Comment: @suish yeah..its the case..I will accept it (unable to upvote due to reputation)